# Django problem with having slug in my url while using a class

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

First i was using a detailslist with a def which was working fine, but i wanted to add a widget to show similar post (post in same category) so i had to change my def to a class to put a def get_context_data(self, pk), but now it always say et_context_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object'

here is my url

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', views.postdetails.as_view(), name="postdetails"),
```

my view

```
class postdetails(DetailView):
model = Post
template_name = 'blog/post.html'

def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(postdetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    cat_id = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=cat_id)
    getcat = category.post_set.all().order_by("-date")
    resultcat = random.sample(getcat,4)

    context['similarpost'] = resultcat
    return context
```

and my model if needed

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, blank=True, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", blank=True)
    body = RichTextField(config_name='default')
    date = models.DateField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I changed the pk in def get_context_data(self,pk): to **kwargs
but i get name 'postdetail' is not defined

thanks a lot

Comment: i tried def get_category(self):
        cat_id = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=cat_id)
        getcat = category.post_set.all().order_by("-date")
        resultcat = random.sample(getcat,4)
        return render(template_name, {'similarpost': resultcat})

Comment: now it show the page, but since its not get_context i cant use for post in similarpost to output some posts

Comment: def get_context_data(self,  **kwargs):

Comment: Remove pk from the function and add **kwargs

Comment: when i do that i get name 'postdetail' is not defined (edit: sorry stupid me had written postdetail instead of postdetails hahah) my code doesnt work doh, how can i get the current post id in the view ? :/

Comment: Inside any function defined inside the class e.g. get_context_data(), self.get_object().id